# Tableau Function - Dates (Day)

Tags: date, visualization, tableau-api, date-formatting, tableau-desktop

I am looking for a tableau formula that would help me create a field that assigns what day number it is in the year. If I use format options the day number restarts every month in the year... I have also tried to create my own formula however it is counting all the days numerically however it does not restart the count after the year ends. I have provided the Formula below:

DATEDIFF('day',DATE('1900-01-01'), [Date: ReportDate]) + 1

I have tried changing the format of the date and I have tried creating a formula to count days and have failed at both :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using : DATEPART('dayofyear', [date])

Assuming you are in a year filtered on 2022, try applying AVG()

[image]

Comment: Mark this as solved, if it helps you